# where is my cookie in my ionic project

Tags: angularjs, cookies, ionic-framework

I'm a fresh with ionic,now I have a trouble with my ionic project.

I create a login.html and then submit my acount information use the $http.post.

here is "Response Headers" in Chrome F12.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 02:34:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 33
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AABAFFBC89AA3A4693296D3A2C2CEA20; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: token=kDkcWXXcjkfzrPj; Expires=Tue, 18-Aug-2015 02:34:06 GMT
Set-Cookie: un=hanxinxin; Expires=Tue, 18-Aug-2015 02:34:06 GMT
```

from this , there are some cookies in my browser.

but when I open the Cookies tools,there are nothing!

```
This site has no cookies
```

So,where are my cookies?Can you tell me?I need your help.

...sorry,my English is poor, but I'm thanks everyone who participated in this discussion.

Comment: Use GapDebug to see where everything is. https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

Comment: Can you tell us how you are navigating to "Cookies tools" (use the words you see on screen)?  Since this question is taged as "angularjs", "cookies", "ionic-framework" and "ionic" and not simply a browser-based issue, it would appear these "Cookie tools" are somewhere in one of those tagged items...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing ionic project just **inspect the device** from chrome and open inspect option it will open java script console and than open resources tab and you will find your cookies in left side menu